# ANTLR's parser enters into "wrong" rule

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter

I'm trying to create an interpreter for a simple programming language using ANTLR. So far it consists of print and numeric expressions. 
I created a 'simpleExpr' parser rule to handle negative numbers. I tried other ways, too, but that's the only one which seems to work right for me. However, for some reason my visitor enters to this rule, even if I would expect it to visit my 'number' rule. I really think, that it's not the visitor's fault, because even the tree drawn by ANTLR shows this behavior. It's weird, but it would be OK, but my problem is, that when I try to print out the result of a simple addition, e.g. print(1+2); then it doesn't do that, but enters into 'number' rule instead of 'Plus' rule.

My grammar:

```
grammar BatshG;
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
compileUnit: (expression | ( println ';') | ( print ';' ))+;
expression:     
                left=expression '/' right=simpleExpr #Divi
            |   left=expression '*' right=simpleExpr #Mult
            |   left=expression '-' right=simpleExpr #Minus
            |   left=expression '+' right=simpleExpr #Plus
            |   number=simpleExpr                    #Number
;
println: 'println' '(' argument=expression ')'; 
print: 'print' '(' argument=expression ')';
simpleExpr
      :   (MINUS)?
          (FLOAT | INTEGER)
      ;
MINUS: '-';
INTEGER: [0-9] [0-9]*;
DIGIT : [0-9]                       ;
FRAC : '.' DIGIT+                   ;
EXP : [eE] [-+]? DIGIT+  ;
FLOAT : DIGIT* FRAC EXP?             ;
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

If it helps, here is my visualized tree generated by ANTLR for

```
print(1+2);
```

[image]

**Update:**
The visitor class, if it counts:

```
public class BatshGVisitor : BatshGBaseVisitor<ResultValue>
{
    public ResultValue Result { get; set; }
    public StringBuilder OutputForPrint { get; set; }

    public override ResultValue VisitCompileUnit([NotNull] BatshGParser.CompileUnitContext context)
    {
        OutputForPrint = new StringBuilder("");
        var resultvalue = VisitChildren(context);
        Result = new ResultValue() { ExpType = "string", ExpValue = resultvalue.ExpValue };
        return Result;
    }

    public override ResultValue VisitPlus([NotNull] BatshGParser.PlusContext context)
    {
        var leftExp = VisitChildren(context.left);
        var rigthExp = VisitChildren(context.right);

        return new ResultValue()
        {
            ExpType = "number",
            ExpValue = (double)leftExp.ExpValue + (double)rigthExp.ExpValue
        };
    }

    //public override ResultValue VisitNumber([NotNull] BatshGParser.NumberContext context)
    //{
    //    return new ResultValue()
    //    {
    //        ExpType = "number",
    //        ExpValue = Double.Parse(context.GetChild(0).GetText() 
    //        + context.GetChild(1).GetText()
    //        + context.GetChild(2).GetText()
    //        , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    //    };
    //}

    public override ResultValue VisitPrint([NotNull] BatshGParser.PrintContext context)
    {
        var viCh = VisitChildren(context.argument);
        var viChVa = viCh.ExpValue;
        string printInner = viChVa.ToString();
        var toPrint = new ResultValue()
        {
            ExpType = viCh.ExpType,
            ExpValue = printInner
        };
        OutputForPrint.Append(toPrint.ExpValue);
        return toPrint;
    }

    public override ResultValue VisitSimpleExpr([NotNull] BatshGParser.SimpleExprContext context)
    {
        string numberToConvert = "";
        if (context.ChildCount == 1)
        {
            numberToConvert = context.GetChild(0).GetText();
        }
        else if (context.GetChild(0).ToString() == "-")
        {
            if (context.ChildCount == 2)
            {
                numberToConvert = "-" + context.GetChild(1);
            }
            if (context.ChildCount == 4)
            {
                numberToConvert = context.GetChild(0).ToString() + context.GetChild(1).ToString() +
                    context.GetChild(2).ToString() + context.GetChild(3).ToString();
            }
        }

        return new ResultValue()
        {
            ExpType = "number",
            ExpValue = Double.Parse(numberToConvert, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        };
    }

    protected override ResultValue AggregateResult(ResultValue aggregate, ResultValue nextResult)
    {
        if (aggregate == null)
            return new ResultValue()
            {
                ExpType = nextResult.ExpType,
                ExpValue = nextResult.ExpValue
            };
        if (nextResult == null)
        {
            return aggregate;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What's the problem with my grammar? 
Thank you!

Comment: All of the alternatives in `expression` contain a `simpleExpr` - also the only way to reach `FLOAT` or `INTEGER` is through `simpleExpr`. So it's not surprising that the parse tree always contains `simpleExpr`s. If you don't want that, you should just make `MINUS? (FLOAT | INTEGER)` one of your alternatives for `expression`.

Comment: That said, there's no actual problem with your grammar (except that `/` and `*` as well as `-` and `+` usually have the same precedence, but don't in your grammar, but that's not what your question is about). You should show us your visitor that doesn't work and explain in more detail how it doesn't work (expected behaviour, actual behaviour).

Comment: @sepp2k it's not surprising. As I mentioned other approaches didn't work for me. For example if I used directly the MINUS? (FLOAT | INTEGER) then when I tried to parse e.g. print(1-2); then it didn't recognise '-' as substraction operator but as part of -2, so there was no operator between two numbers so it run into error. But maybe you're right and I shouldn't expect to enter the 'number' rule if there is 'simpleExpr'.

Comment: There is no `Number` rule - there's a `Number` alternative in the `expression` rule. And you do enter that. The generated parse tree node will have type `NumberContext` (which extends `ExpressionContext`), it's just not displayed as such in the tree in the GUI because it displays the names of the rules, not the names of the alternatives.

Comment: "if I used directly the MINUS? (FLOAT | INTEGER) then when I tried to parse e.g. print(1-2); then it didn't recognise '-' as substraction operator but as part of -2" I don't see why that would happen, so I think you actually did something else (like allowing `INTEGER` and `FLOAT` to start with a `-` or creating a `NUMBER` token that can start with a `-`), mixed up the result of trying different things or misinterpreted what was happening.

Comment: @sepp2k "That said, there's no actual problem with your grammar (except that / and * as well as - and + usually have the same precedence, but don't in your grammar,...)" -  well, I have seen this way in a tutorial, and it should solve the problems about computing numeric expressions in the correct order. However, it does not work for me (after solving my main question). It works like if the '+' and '*' where in the same precedence...

Comment: @sepp2k "so I think you actually did something else (like allowing INTEGER and FLOAT to start with a - or creating a NUMBER token that can start with a -)"
I think, you are right. Now I replaced simpleExpr with "MINUS? (FLOAT | INTEGER)" and the  part of recognizing of negative numbers and minus operator works fine.

Comment: Oh, yes. That's because the right operand is always `simpleExpr`, which forces left-to-right order (I missed that at first). But if you fix that (by making both operands `expression`), the precedence will still be wrong because `/` will have higher precedence than `*` and `-` than `+` (they should have equal precedence).

Comment: @sepp2k Now I changed my grammar and used     "expression"     on both left and right side of expression, but this way there is the problem of recognizing the minus operator, again. ANTLR thinks it's a minus sign.

Comment: Can you show your current grammar, your test input and the error message you get for that input?

Comment: My current grammar: https://pastebin.com/yjvHLwEd
Test input: print(11-2); - returns 11 (always the first argument).
I also tried to generate the visualized tree and it says it's 
print   (  expression     -2).   Recognizes -2 as one token.

Comment: Get rid of the `SIMPLEE` token. You can't have a number tojen that starts with a minus, the minus sign needs to be its own token.

Comment: @sepp2k Should I use a parse rule instead though, like the "simpleExpr"? When I try to substitute directly the (MINUS?) (FLOAT | INTEGER) then I get compile error "label 'number' assigned to a block which is not a set"

Comment: Ah, that's because you can't have an alternation (like `(INT | FLOAT)` within a named alternative. Also you probably shouldn't tie `-` to number literals like that (something like `-x` or `-(larger expression)` should be possible as well, right), so I'd recommend something like `INT # Int | FLOAT # Float | '-' expression # Negation | ...`

Comment: @sepp2 Would you possibly see an other question of mine in the topic, please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724871/why-does-parser-generated-by-antlr-reuse-context-objects? I'm stucked again with this interpreter...
I hope I don't any violate rules with request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the visit method for print statements, you have this:

```
var viCh = VisitChildren(context.argument);
```

So let's say your input was `print(1+2);`. Then `context.argument` would be the `PlusContext` for `1+2` and the children of `context.argument` would be a `NumberContext` for 1, a `Token` object for `+` and a `SimpleExpression` object for 2. So by calling `VisitChildren`, you're going to visit those children, which is why it never runs `VisitPlus` and goes directly to the numbers.

Generally, you rarely want to visit the children of some other node. You usually want to visit your own children, not skip the children and directly visit the grand children. So what you should do instead is to call `Visit(context.argument);`.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I used VisitChildren in several places instead of Visit. In rule 'compileUnit' it seems to be good, because we don't know how many "print"s are there, but that's not the case inside print.

Comment: @Geff The important difference in `compilationUnit` is that there you're calling `VisitChildren` on the current node, not on a child of the current node (or some other node). As a rule, anything except calling it on the current node is almost always wrong (though I'm sure there are use cases where it's not).