# Why does parser generated by ANTLR reuse context objects?

Tags: c#, object, scope, antlr, interpreter

I'm trying to create an interpreter for a simple programming language using ANTLR.
I would like to add the feature of recursion.

So far I have implemented the definition and calling functions with option of using several return statements and also local variables. To achieve having local variables I extended the parser partial class of `FunctionCallContext` with a dictionary for them. I can successfully use them for one time. Also, when I call the same function again from itself (recursively), the parser creates a new context object for the new function call, as I would expect. 
However,if I create a "deeper" recursion, the third context of the function call will be the very same as the second (having the same hash code and the same local variables).

My (updated) grammar:

```
    grammar BatshG;
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
compileUnit: ( (statement) | functionDef)+;
statement:      print  ';'
            |   println ';'
            |   assignment ';'
            |   loopWhile
            |   branch 
            |   returnStatement ';'
            |   functionCall ';'
;

branch:
          'if' '(' condition=booleanexpression ')' 
                trueBranch=block 
            ('else' falseBranch=block)?;
loopWhile:
          'while' '(' condition=booleanexpression ')' 
                whileBody=block 
;

block: 
                statement
            |   '{' statement* '}';

numericexpression:      
                MINUS onepart=numericexpression               #UnaryMinus
            |   left=numericexpression op=('*'|'/') right=numericexpression  #MultOrDiv
            |   left=numericexpression op=('+'|'-') right=numericexpression  #PlusOrMinus
            |   number=NUMERIC                                      #Number
            |   variableD                                       #NumVariable
;
stringexpression: 
                left=stringexpression PLUSPLUS right=stringexpression #Concat   
            |   string=STRING #String
            |   variableD                                       #StrVariable
            |   numericexpression #NumberToString
;
booleanexpression:
                        left=numericexpression relationalOperator=('<' | '>' | '>=' | '<=' | '==' | '!=' ) right=numericexpression #RelationalOperation
                    |   booleanliteral #Boolean
                    |   numericexpression #NumberToBoolean
;
booleanliteral: trueConst | falseConst ;
trueConst :  'true'          ;
falseConst :  'false'                ;

assignment : varName=IDENTIFIER EQUAL  right=expression;
expression: numericexpression | stringexpression | functionCall | booleanexpression;
println: 'println' '(' argument=expression ')'; 
print: 'print' '(' argument=expression ')';

functionDef: 'function' funcName= IDENTIFIER
                        '(' 
                            (functionParameters=parameterList)?
                        ')'
                            '{' 
                                statements=statementPart?
                            '}' 
;

statementPart:  statement* ;
returnStatement: ('return' returnValue=expression );
parameterList : paramName=IDENTIFIER (',' paramName=IDENTIFIER)*;

functionCall: funcName=IDENTIFIER '(' 
            (functionArguments=argumentList)?
')';
argumentList: expression (',' expression)*;
variableD: varName=IDENTIFIER;
///*
// * Lexer Rules
// */
NUMERIC: (FLOAT | INTEGER);
PLUSPLUS: '++';
MINUS: '-';
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;

EQUAL  :            '='              ;

STRING : '"' (~["\r\n] | '""')* '"'          ;

INTEGER: [0-9] [0-9]*;
DIGIT : [0-9]                       ;
FRAC : '.' DIGIT+                   ;
EXP : [eE] [-+]? DIGIT+  ;
FLOAT : DIGIT* FRAC EXP?             ;
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);

    ///*
    // * Lexer Rules
    // */
    NUMERIC: (FLOAT | INTEGER);
    PLUSPLUS: '++';
    MINUS: '-';
    IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
    EQUAL  :            '='              ;
    STRING : '"' (~["\r\n] | '""')* '"'          ;
    INTEGER: [0-9] [0-9]*;
    DIGIT : [0-9]                       ;
    FRAC : '.' DIGIT+                   ;
    EXP : [eE] [-+]? DIGIT+  ;
    FLOAT : DIGIT* FRAC EXP?             ;
    WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

My partial class of parser written by me (not the generated part):

```
    public partial class BatshGParser
{
    //"extensions" for contexts:
    public partial class FunctionCallContext
    {
        private Dictionary<string, object> localVariables = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        private bool isFunctionReturning;
        public FunctionCallContext()
        {
           localVariables = new Dictionary<string, object>();
           isFunctionReturning = false;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, object> LocalVariables { get => localVariables; set => localVariables = value; }
        public bool IsFunctionReturning { get => isFunctionReturning; set => isFunctionReturning = value; }
    }

    public partial class FunctionDefContext
    {
        private List<string> parameterNames;

        public FunctionDefContext()
        {
            parameterNames = new List<string>();
        }
        public List<string> ParameterNames { get => parameterNames; set => parameterNames = value; }
    }
}
```

And relevant parts (and maybe a little more) of my visitor:

```
         public class BatshGVisitor : BatshGBaseVisitor<ResultValue>
    {
        public ResultValue Result { get; set; }
        public StringBuilder OutputForPrint { get; set; }
        private Dictionary<string, object> globalVariables = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        //string = function name
        //object = parameter list
        //object =  return value
        private Dictionary<string, Func<List<object>, object>> globalFunctions = new Dictionary<string, Func<List<object>, object>>();
        private Stack<BatshGParser.FunctionCallContext> actualFunctions = new Stack<BatshGParser.FunctionCallContext>();

        public override ResultValue VisitCompileUnit([NotNull] BatshGParser.CompileUnitContext context)
        {
            OutputForPrint = new StringBuilder("");

            isSearchingForFunctionDefinitions = true;
            var resultvalue = VisitChildren(context);
            isSearchingForFunctionDefinitions = false;
            resultvalue = VisitChildren(context);
            Result = new ResultValue() { ExpType = "string", ExpValue = resultvalue.ExpValue ?? null };

            return Result;
        }
        public override ResultValue VisitChildren([NotNull] IRuleNode node)
        {
            if (this.isSearchingForFunctionDefinitions)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    if (node.GetChild(i) is BatshGParser.FunctionDefContext)
                    {
                        Visit(node.GetChild(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            return base.VisitChildren(node);
        }
        protected override bool ShouldVisitNextChild([NotNull] IRuleNode node, ResultValue currentResult)
        {
            if (isSearchingForFunctionDefinitions)
            {
                if (node is BatshGParser.FunctionDefContext)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (node is BatshGParser.FunctionDefContext)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    return base.ShouldVisitNextChild(node, currentResult);
            }
        }

        public override ResultValue VisitFunctionDef([NotNull] BatshGParser.FunctionDefContext context)
        {

            string functionName = null;
            functionName = context.funcName.Text;
            if (context.functionParameters != null)
            {
                List<string> plist = CollectParamNames(context.functionParameters);
                context.ParameterNames = plist;
            }
            if (isSearchingForFunctionDefinitions)
                globalFunctions.Add(functionName,
                (
                delegate(List<object> args)
                    {
                        var currentMethod = (args[0] as BatshGParser.FunctionCallContext);
                        this.actualFunctions.Push(currentMethod);
                        //args[0] is the context
                        for (int i = 1; i < args.Count; i++)
                        {

                            currentMethod.LocalVariables.Add(context.ParameterNames[i - 1],
                                (args[i] as ResultValue).ExpValue
                                );
                        }

                    ResultValue retval = null;
                        retval = this.VisitStatementPart(context.statements);

                        this.actualFunctions.Peek().IsFunctionReturning = false;
                        actualFunctions.Pop();
                        return retval;
                    }
                 )
            );
            return new ResultValue()
            {

            };
        }       

        public override ResultValue VisitStatementPart([NotNull] BatshGParser.StatementPartContext context)
        {
            if (!this.actualFunctions.Peek().IsFunctionReturning)
            {
                return VisitChildren(context);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public override ResultValue VisitReturnStatement([NotNull] BatshGParser.ReturnStatementContext context)
        {
            this.actualFunctions.Peek().IsFunctionReturning = true;
            ResultValue retval = null;
            if (context.returnValue != null)
            {
                retval = Visit(context.returnValue);
            }

            return retval;
        }

                public override ResultValue VisitArgumentList([NotNull] BatshGParser.ArgumentListContext context)
        {
            List<ResultValue> argumentList = new List<ResultValue>();
            foreach (var item in context.children)
            {
                var tt = item.GetText();
                if (item.GetText() != ",")
                {
                    ResultValue rv = Visit(item);
                    argumentList.Add(rv);
                }
            }
            return
                new ResultValue()
                {
                    ExpType = "list",
                    ExpValue = argumentList ?? null
                };
        }

        public override ResultValue VisitFunctionCall([NotNull] BatshGParser.FunctionCallContext context)
        {
            string functionName = context.funcName.Text;
            int hashcodeOfContext = context.GetHashCode();
            object functRetVal = null;
            List<object> argumentList = new List<object>()
            {
                context
                //here come the actual parameters later
            };

            ResultValue argObjects = null;
            if (context.functionArguments != null)
            {
                argObjects = VisitArgumentList(context.functionArguments);
            }

            if (argObjects != null )
            {
                if (argObjects.ExpValue is List<ResultValue>)
                {
                    var argresults = (argObjects.ExpValue as List<ResultValue>) ?? null;
                    foreach (var arg in argresults)
                    {
                        argumentList.Add(arg);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (globalFunctions.ContainsKey(functionName))
            {
                {
                    functRetVal = globalFunctions[functionName]( argumentList );
                }
            }

            return new ResultValue()
            {
                ExpType = ((ResultValue)functRetVal).ExpType,
                ExpValue = ((ResultValue)functRetVal).ExpValue
            };
        }

        public override ResultValue VisitVariableD([NotNull] BatshGParser.VariableDContext context)
        {

            object variable;
            string variableName = context.GetChild(0).ToString();
            string typename = "";

            Dictionary<string, object> variables = null;
            if (actualFunctions.Count > 0)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> localVariables = 
                    actualFunctions.Peek().LocalVariables;
                if (localVariables.ContainsKey(variableName))
                {
                    variables = localVariables;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                variables = globalVariables;
            }

            if (variables.ContainsKey(variableName))
            {
                variable = variables[variableName];

                typename = charpTypesToBatshTypes[variable.GetType()];
            }
            else
            {

                Type parentContextType = contextTypes[context.parent.GetType()];
                typename = charpTypesToBatshTypes[parentContextType];
                variable = new object();

                if (typename.Equals("string"))
                {
                    variable = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    variable = 0d;
                }
            }

            return new ResultValue()
            {
                ExpType = typename,
                ExpValue = variable
            };
        }           
        public override ResultValue VisitAssignment([NotNull] BatshGParser.AssignmentContext context)
        {
            string varname = context.varName.Text;
            ResultValue varAsResultValue = Visit(context.right);
            Dictionary<string, object> localVariables = null;

            if (this.actualFunctions.Count > 0)
            {
                localVariables = 
                    actualFunctions.Peek().LocalVariables;
                if (localVariables.ContainsKey(varname))
                {
                    localVariables[varname] = varAsResultValue.ExpValue;
                }
                else
                if (globalVariables.ContainsKey(varname))
                {
                    globalVariables[varname] = varAsResultValue.ExpValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    localVariables.Add(varname, varAsResultValue.ExpValue);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (globalVariables.ContainsKey(varname))
                {
                    globalVariables[varname] = varAsResultValue.ExpValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    globalVariables.Add(varname, varAsResultValue.ExpValue);
                }
            }
            return varAsResultValue;
        }
}
```

What could cause the problem? Thank you!

Comment: The hash would only be the same if  context.funcName.Text was the same.  So when you are recursively going through the code the name must be a combined name of all the parents names like "root" + "^" + "child" + "^" + "grandchild".  You should use a character joining character to make sure the hash is unique. because "grand" + "child" will give same hash as "grandchild".

Comment: @jdweng Well, maybe we could be more confident in the equality of the two objects, but I think  the hash code does not depend only on the text of `funcName`. And also I use the name of the function as a key in `globalFunctions` so I wouldn't like it change it, if not necessary.

Comment: Still to be unique the hash code need to include all the ancestors.  So you have to combine the names together.  Adding the "^" will remove any duplication.

Comment: @jdweng What exactly do you mean by 'ancestor'? context.parent? Or the method calling this function in C#'s stack? Or the calling function in my programming language? Or the parent rule in ANTLR grammar? Or...? 
And how would it help me to solve my original problem?

Comment: You siad following : " However,if I create a "deeper" recursion, the third context of the function call will be the very same as the second (having the same hash code and the same local variables)".  If you just used name then 2nd and 3rd names are the same. Doing my way you have "Parent^Child" and "Parent^Child^Child".

Comment: @jdweng I would like to use the same name (or otherwise what's the function definiton for?) but with other context. The context would differentiate them. If you look it in detail, actually my 'real' function call is not calling the `VisitFunctionCall` method, but calling the delegate from `globalFunctions` dictionary, which is instantiated in `VisitFunctionDef` and which get the current context and the arguments from `VisitFunctionCall` .

Comment: Is the parser really reusing objects? Or are you just visiting the same part of the tree multiple times?

Comment: Either way, I think it's a bad idea to add mutable state to the Context classes, which looks like what you're doing. The mutable state should live in your visitor, not the visitees.

Comment: @sepp2k "Is the parser really reusing objects? Or are you just visiting the same part of the tree multiple times?"  I think actually it's visiting the same part of the tree multiple times. ANTLR doesn't know, how many times I need to use those parts while creating the parse tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does parser generated by ANTLR reuse context objects?

It doesn't. Each function call in your source code will correspond to exactly one `FunctionCallContext` object and those will be unique. They'd have to be, even for two entirely identical function calls, because they also contain meta data, such as where in the source the function call appears - and that's obviously going to differ between calls even if everything else is the same.

To illustrate this, consider the following source code:

```
function f(x) {
  return f(x);
}
print(f(x));
```

This will create a tree containing exactly two `FunctionCallContext` objects - one for line 2 and one for line 4. They will both be distinct - they'll both have child nodes referring to the function name `f` and the argument `x`, but they'll have different location information and a different hash code - as will the child nodes. Nothing is being reused here.

> What could cause the problem?

The fact that you're seeing the same node multiple times is simply due to the fact that you're visiting the same part of the tree multiple times. That's a perfectly normal thing to do for your use case, but in your case it causes a problem because you stored mutable data in the object, assuming that you'd get a fresh `FunctionCall` object for each time a function call happens at run time - rather than each time a function call appears in the source code.

That's not how parse trees work (they represent the structure of the source code, not the sequence of calls that might happen at run time), so you can't use `FunctionCallContext` objects to store information about a specific run-time function call. In general, I'd consider it a bad idea to put mutable state into context objects.

Instead you should put your mutable state into your visitor object. For your specific problem that means having a call stack containing the local variables of each run-time function call. Each time a function starts execution, you can push a frame onto the stack and each time a function exits, you can pop it. That way the top of the stack will always contain the local variables of the function currently being executed.

---

PS: This is unrelated to your problem, but the usual rules of precedence in arithmetic expressions are such that, `+` has the same precedence as `-` and `*` has the same precedence as `/`. In your grammar the precedence of `/` is greater than that of `*` and that of `-` higher than `+`. This means that for example `9 * 5 / 3` is going to evaluate to `5`, when it should be `15` (assuming the usual rules for integer arithmetic).

To fix this `+` and `-`, as well as `*` and `/` should be part of the same rule, so they get the same precedence:

```
| left=numericexpression op=('*'|'/') right=numericexpression #MulOrDiv
| left=numericexpression op=('+'|'-') right=numericexpression #PlusOrMinus
```

Comment: Thank you! Now instead of context I use a separate objects. I created a `FunctionState` class for it which stores the local variables (including the arguments) and the `IsFunctionReturning` flat to determine whether is evaluation of current statement (after first return statement) needed.

Comment: Mathematically said the * and /  operators and + / - operators really have the same precedence, but so far I didn't have problems with current solution. For example `9 * 5 / 3` results `15`, as expected.

Comment: However I have problem with precedence in other place: for example when I try to evaluate this part of a function - `return fibonacci(num - 2) + fibonacci(num - 1);` then it does not recognize the + as numeric statement and only computes the first part, as it would be `return fibonacci(num - 2);` It's not better if I change this line of the grammer: `returnStatement: ('return' returnValue=expression);` to this: `returnStatement: ('return' returnValue=expression (. expression)?);
It seems like function call would have higher precedence, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Geff Do you not perform integer arithmetic then? Because with reals `(9*5)/3` and `9*(5/3)` are indeed equivalent. Your other problem is not due to precedence, but the fact that your grammar simply does not allow function calls as an operand to `+` because function calls aren't `numericexpression`s. That problem goes away if you merge all of your expression rules (`numericexpression`, `stringexpression`, `boolexpression`, `functioncall`) into a single rule named `expression`.

Comment: I decided not using integer arithmetics for now. But anyway, I changed it to your solution, because it simplifies the things - or at least I need less code.
Would not using only 1 expression type mess up the things about arithmetics and mainly boolean expressions?

Comment: @Geff You mean because it allows things like "true + 1"? That's the type checker's job to fix (or the interpreter's/runtime's in a dynamically typed language) - not the parser's. That's how it works in real-world languages/implementations as well.

Comment: "You mean because it allows things like "true + 1"?" - yes and about unassigned variables. And it really messed up things around handling of unassigned variables (e.g. need to be able to concatenate two strings or variables even when one of them is unassigned - empty.   `a ="Hello"; a=a++f;print(a);` should print out "Hello". On the other it should work with numbers, too. But you are right, I need to improve the "type checker" (btw, it's interpreted/dynamically typed language). 
At least recursion already works :)